# Recursive method to print value of each array index in order

Tags: java

I am trying to write a recursive method that prints out each index of an array. My Hand class represents a hand of five cards, using a Card[] cards of length 5. Below is my method so far. It works but is there a better way to do this instead of having an integer parameter of the index to start from? Please help.

```
public static void printHandForward (Hand hand, int index) {
    if(index == hand.cards.length) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        Card.printCard(hand.cards[index]);
        index++;
        printHandForward(hand, index);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could just not have it be recursive.

Comment: A better way would be to use an enhanced for statement rather than recursion.

Comment: So you are calling this method and passing in the first index?

Answer (score 1):

If you must use recursion, you have to call this method with an int parameter somehow.

You can simply add an overload which just takes `Hand`, which calls your current method:

```
public static void printHandForward(Hand hand) {
  printHandForward(hand, 0);
}
```

However, avoiding recusion and just using an enhanced for statement would be much easier.

Comment: @vishalgajera Do you understand what is meant by an overload?

Comment: @vishalgajera your comment does not parse in English.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need a recursive method, and you couldn't use just:

```
public static void printHandForward (Hand hand) {
    for(Card card: hand.cards) {
        Card.printCard(card);
    }
}
```

?

If you really need a recursive method, I recommend use a following code:

```
printHandForward(hand, hand.length);
...
public static void printHandForward (Hand hand, int index) {
    if(index > -1) {
       printHandForward(hand, index -1);
       Card.printCard(hand.cards[index]);
    }
}
```